# invisible bridged router with 2 route table

Tags: linux, networking, routing

**my setup**

I have 2 ISP connexion : ADSL and SDSL.
A qos (named qos, ip : 192.9.201.252)  server stands before the ADSL router. It is the only way to access the ADSL gateway (192.9.201.254)
through a bridge (br0).
so this qos server is invisible and can easily be unplugged if it fails.

As for now, the default gateway of all LAN computers is 192.9.201.254, and so all traffic pass through the qos.

This setup work very well.

**my need**

Now, I need to route a defined service (isl) (already marked by iptable for  the qos purpose) to the SDSL (192.9.201.251) gateway.

I can achieve that by creating another route table named «isl» and create the default gateway pointing to the SDSL router.

after that, I create a rule that

```
grep "30 isl" /etc/iproute2/rt_tables || echo "30 isl" >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
ip route add default via 192.9.201.251 dev br0 table isl
ip rule add fwmark 0x1e table isl
```

with this setup, I work if I change all default gateway to 192.9.201.252.

**my question**

how to force these routing table to apply even if the hosts don't have my qos server as gateway, but always the ADSL router

my thought was to use some iptables rules to NAT all marked packet to local host, which will then redirect traffic to SDSL, but I feel wrong with that.